# Scheduled query to append data to partitioned BigQuery table - incompatible table partitioning specification

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to append data to a table partitioned by month using the BQ Console.

The SQL used to create the table and partition was:

CREATE TABLE xxxxxx
PARTITION BY DATE_TRUNC(Event_Dt, MONTH)

I used Event_Dt as the partitioned field in BQ Console:

[image]

The scheduled query does not run and I get the following error message:

"Incompatible table partitioning specification. Destination table exists with partitioning specification interval(type:MONTH,field:Event_Dt), but transfer target partitioning specification is interval(type:DAY,field:Event_Dt). Please retry after updating either the destination table or the transfer partitioning specification."

How do I enter Event_Dt in the BQ Console to indicate that it is partitioned by month and not day?

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem. All I needed to do was remove Event_Dt from the Destination table partitioning field in the BQ Console.  The partitioned table updated successfully when I left the field blank.